# Use a texfield to search/filter an treeview

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

i have been trying to find an answer to this but it seems like hell of a complicated to do.

What i want to do is that i have a treeview and with an textfield i want to be able to search so only the treeitems in the treeview that matches whats on the textfield shows.

for example if someone writes "lat" in the textfield the treeview shows folders like "latency" "latvia" and so on.

the treeview fill code is as this

```
@FXML
private void fillTreeView() {
    // The tree needs a root, and it needs to be a DocumentObject
    // so we create an empty folder and hide it
    TreeItem<DocumentObject<?>> treeRoot = new TreeItem<>(new Folder());

    for (Folder folder : logic.getFolderList()) {
        TreeItem<DocumentObject<?>> folderNode = new TreeItem<>(folder);

        for (FileReference file : folder.getFileList()) {
            TreeItem<DocumentObject<?>> fileNode = new TreeItem<>(file);
            folderNode.getChildren().add(fileNode);
        }

        treeRoot.getChildren().add(folderNode);
        treeRoot.setExpanded(true);
    }

    treeNav.setRoot(treeRoot);
    treeNav.setShowRoot(false);
}
```

and then i want the Textfield to seach both treeitems and display what the user searched for

Comment: Some code would be great.

Comment: @Sedrick added how the treeview is built. but i dont even know were to start on how to search/filter it

Comment: So your `Tree` is always only two deep?

Comment: @Sedrick yeah its always two deep

Comment: I am going to try to see if I can come up with a sample app.

Comment: @Sedrick that would be awsome! I have been ripping my hair about this :)

Comment: Are you only filtering at one level? (I.e. just filtering the direct children of the root node?) If so it's not too bad. Or do you want to filter the entire tree: that is more complex.

Comment: @James_D provided you with a better answer than what I was doing.

Comment: have a look at http://www.kware.net/?p=204 for a working though dirty approach (reflectively replaces the internal children list with a filteredList)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only filtering the direct children of the root node, it's fairly straightforward. Just keep the top level nodes in a separate `ObservableList`, wrap a `FilteredList` around it, and then use `Bindings.bindContent()` to make sure the child node list of the root node contains the same elements as the `FilteredList`.

Assuming your `DocumentObject` has a method, say `getName()` that returns the text against which you want to apply the filter, and you have a `TextField` called `textField` where the user types the filter text, this would look something like:

```
@FXML
private void fillTreeView() {
    // The tree needs a root, and it needs to be a DocumentObject
    // so we create an empty folder and hide it
    TreeItem<DocumentObject<?>> treeRoot = new TreeItem<>(new Folder());

    ObservableList<TreeItem<DocumentObject<?>>> firstLevel = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for (Folder folder : logic.getFolderList()) {
        TreeItem<DocumentObject<?>> folderNode = new TreeItem<>(folder);

        for (FileReference file : folder.getFileList()) {
            TreeItem<DocumentObject<?>> fileNode = new TreeItem<>(file);
            folderNode.getChildren().add(fileNode);
        }

        firstLevel.add(folderNode);
    }

    treeRoot.setExpanded(true);


    FilteredList<TreeItem<DocumentObject<?>>> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(firstLevel, item -> true);

    filteredList.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        String filter = textField.getText();
        if (filter.isEmpty()) return item -> true ;
        return item -> item.getValue().getName().startsWith(filter) ; // your implementation may vary...
    }, textField.textProperty());

    Bindings.bindContent(treeRoot.getChildren(), filteredList);

    treeNav.setRoot(treeRoot);
    treeNav.setShowRoot(false);
}
```

If you want to filter the entire tree, then you need to do the same at each level....

Comment: you probably are aware of kware.net/?p=204 ... it's for a working though dirty approach (reflectively replaces the internal children list with a filteredList)

Comment: @kleopatra, there is an updated version of the class [here](https://github.com/eclipse-efx/efxclipse-rt/blob/3.x/modules/ui/org.eclipse.fx.ui.controls/src/main/java/org/eclipse/fx/ui/controls/tree/FilterableTreeItem.java) that doesn't use reflection. He mentions it at the bottom in the comment section.

Comment: @wcmatthysen wasn't aware of the update, thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this filter to fire more than once. I'm not using a textfield's property, but just a SimpleObjectProperty I'm maintaining in the class. When I update the value of the property via set(), the filter doesn't seem to fire again.