# ChangeListener in a TreeTableView CheckBoxTreeTableCell getting triggered many times every click

Tags: java, javafx

I have a simple model class Person and I use it to populate a TreeTableView. I want to have one column with a checkbox and I want to populate another TreeTableView with the data I check in the first table. Seems reasonable but my problem is the ChangeListener added to the BooleanProperty via the SetCellValueFactory is triggered many times, 4 to 8 times randomly (or so it seems random, I did not really test that).

Main class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChangeListenerBug extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    // create the treeTableView and colums
    TreeTableView<Person> ttv = new TreeTableView<Person>();
    TreeTableColumn<Person, String> colName = new TreeTableColumn<>("Name");
    TreeTableColumn<Person, Boolean> colSelected = new TreeTableColumn<>("Selected");
    ttv.getColumns().add(colName);
    ttv.getColumns().add(colSelected);
    ttv.setShowRoot(false);
    ttv.setEditable(true);
    colSelected.setEditable(true);

    // set the columns
    colName.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    colSelected.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn(colSelected));
    colSelected.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
        // binding the cell property with the model
        BooleanProperty selected = cellData.getValue().getValue().selectedProperty();
        // listening for a change in the property
        selected.addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            System.out.println(newVal);// WHY IS THIS GETTING CALLED MULTIPLE TIMES
        });
        return selected;
    });

    // creating treeItems to populate the treetableview
    TreeItem<Person> rootTreeItem = new TreeItem<Person>();
    rootTreeItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<Person>(new Person("Name 1")));
    rootTreeItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<Person>(new Person("Name 2")));
    ttv.setRoot(rootTreeItem);

    // build and show the window
    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().add(ttv);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300));
    stage.show();
}
}
```

Person Class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {
private StringProperty name;
private BooleanProperty selected;

public Person(String name) {
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
}

public StringProperty nameProperty() {return name;}

public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {return selected;}

public void setName(String name){this.name.set(name);}

public void setSelected(boolean selected){this.selected.set(selected);}
}
```

Output when I check a checkbox (same but false when I deselect it) :

```
true
true
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cellData.getValue().getValue().selectedProperty()` doesn’t create a new BooleanProperty.  For any given Person object, it returns the same BooleanProperty again and again, and you keep adding yet another listener to that same BooleanProperty, again and again.

Do not add a listener in your cellValueFactory.  Add the listener *once* to each Person object.

Since your tree is only one level deep (aside from the root), you can just iterate through them:

```
rootTreeItem.getChildren().forEach(item -> {
    BooleanProperty selected = item.getValue().selectedProperty();

    selected.addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        System.out.println(newVal);
    });
});
```

If the tree had multiple levels, you’d need a recursive method:

```
    listenForSelection(rootTreeItem,
        selected -> System.out.println(selected));

// ...

private void listenForSelection(TreeItem<Person> treeItem,
                                Consumer<Boolean> listener) {

    BooleanProperty selected = treeItem.getValue().selectedProperty();

    selected.addListener(
        (obs, oldVal, newVal) -> listener.accept(newVal));

    treeItem.getChildren().forEach(item -> listenForSelection(item, listener));
}
```

Comment: That works, it also seems to works by creating a change listener outside the setcellValueFactory and then  `selected.removeListener(changelistener); selected.addListener(changelistener);` inside the setcellValueFactory but I understand that seems ugly.  I am surprised it works that way, I was suspecting the CellValueFactory would be called once for each cell and it would work the way I intended, is there something I am missing?

Comment: I can’t seem to find explicit documentation of this, but I believe it works similar to Swing’s TableModel:  it can be called many times even for the same cell, in order to support dynamic rendering.  This allows you to construct a table of thousands of items, without keeping every corresponding cell in memory at all times.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a step back to address your underlying requirement:

> I want to have one column with a checkbox and I want to populate another TreeTableView with the data I check in the first table

An alternative to manual listening (as in your attempt and the good [answer provided by VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52486549/203657)) is to indirectly bind the content of the other treeTable to a filtered version of the first, [as outlined by James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48674004/203657).

Applied to your context (single level only):

```
public class TreeTableDriveTreeTableWithSelected extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    FilteredList<TreeItem<Person>>  targetItems;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        // create the treeTableView and colums
        TreeTableView<Person> source = createTreeTable(true);
        // creating treeItems to populate the treetableview
        TreeItem<Person> sourceRoot = createRootItem();
        source.setRoot(sourceRoot);

        TreeTableView<Person> target = createTreeTable(false);
        TreeItem<Person> targetRoot = new TreeItem<>();
        target.setRoot(targetRoot);

        // backing list for filteredList, configured to fire updates on change
        // of selected
        ObservableList<TreeItem<Person>> backingTargetItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                item -> new ObservableValue[] {item.getValue().selectedProperty()} 
        );

        // fill backing list with items of source
        // note: treeItems can't be shared across trees, so need to create with same value
        sourceRoot.getChildren()
            .forEach(tp -> backingTargetItems.add(new TreeItem<>(tp.getValue())));
        // filter the backing list by its selected property
        // this must be a strong reference, otherwise the binding is garbage-collected
        targetItems = new FilteredList<>(backingTargetItems, 
                p -> p.getValue().isSelected()
        );
        // bind content of target root to filtered list
        Bindings.bindContent(targetRoot.getChildren(), targetItems);

        // build and show the window
        HBox root = new HBox(10);
        root.getChildren().addAll(source, target);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300));
        stage.show();
    }

    protected TreeItem<Person> createRootItem() {
        TreeItem<Person> rootTreeItem = new TreeItem<Person>();
        rootTreeItem.getChildren()
                .add(new TreeItem<Person>(new Person("Name 1")));
        rootTreeItem.getChildren()
                .add(new TreeItem<Person>(new Person("Name 2")));
        return rootTreeItem;
    }

    protected TreeTableView<Person> createTreeTable(boolean withSelected) {
        TreeTableView<Person> ttv = new TreeTableView<Person>();
        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> colName = new TreeTableColumn<>("Name");
        colName.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        ttv.getColumns().add(colName);
        ttv.setShowRoot(false);

        if (withSelected) {
            ttv.setEditable(true);
            // column editable is true by default
            //  colSelected.setEditable(true);

            TreeTableColumn<Person, Boolean> colSelected = new TreeTableColumn<>(
                    "Selected");
            ttv.getColumns().add(colSelected);
            // set the columns
            // updating the property
            colSelected.setCellFactory(
                    CheckBoxTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn(colSelected));
            colSelected.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("selected"));
        }
        return ttv;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution, however my requirement is a little bit more complicated than what I explained in the question. I need to have more control over what happens when an item is checked in my source table. Building a GUI for a shop in a game, I have an inventory table and a confirm-transaction table. When an item is checked I want to populate the confirm-transaction table but with a copy of the item so I can edit it (for example the quantity of it) directly in the transaction table. Also I am unsure how I can create an backing observable list if I have more levels in the TreeTableView.

Comment: real life is always more complicated than examples, isn't it :) As to the copy: you can use copies of the value object in the second tree vs the original (just change the predicate). As to several levels: either do it for each (tedious) or have a look at a filtered tree (reference is in a comment to james' answer) which uses reflection to replace the treeItem's internal children field (not sure if that's still working, had trouble with it some time back ..)